# SDL 2.0 C++: Polymorphism Vectors, my objects are not loading different images

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

So I'm basically following a book called SDL Game Development by Shaun Mitchell.
I'm current on page 58, where it tells us how to implement polymorphism.

So far what I have down are:
- Create the main code where we do all our rendering updating etc. (Game.cpp and Game.h)
- Create a Texture manager as a singleton (TextureManager.h and TextureManager.cpp)
- Create a GameObject (GameObject.h and GameObject.cpp)
- Create a Player that inherits GameObject (Player.h and Player.cpp)

So my GameObject class basically has 3 methods: load, draw and update.
Load basically loads an image, and I use my TextureManager to do so.
Draw draws it and update just changes it positions and current frame.

I pass the name of the image which is basically the directory, the renderer and the textureID from the Game class where I call them.

Essentially the problem is that I pass in two different directories into a GameObject
and a Player, but it only loads up the last directory I pass in. As in both GameObject and Player becomes the same image.

So I think the problem lies in Game class, Player class or GameObject class.
I create the objects in Game class, and push them in vector at Game.cpp in init function
Where it says

```
    m_go->load(100, 100, 96, 60, "assets/simba.bmp", "animate",m_pRenderer);    
    m_player->load(300, 300, 96, 60, "assets/download.bmp", "animate",m_pRenderer);
```

GameObject.h

```
#ifndef GAMEOBJECT_H
#define GAMEOBJECT_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL_image.h"
#include "TextureManager.h"

class GameObject
{
    public:
        virtual bool load(int x, int y, int width, int height, std::string name, std::string textureID, SDL_Renderer* pRenderer);
        virtual void draw(SDL_Renderer* pRenderer);
        virtual void update();
        virtual void clean();
    protected:
        std::string m_textureID;
        int m_currentFrame;
        int m_currentRow;
        int m_x;
        int m_y;
        int m_width;
        int m_height;
};

#endif // GAMEOBJECT_H
```

GameObject.cpp

```
#include "GameObject.h"

bool GameObject::load(int x, int y, int width, int height, std::string name, std::string textureID, SDL_Renderer* pRenderer)
{
    m_x = x;
    m_y = y;
    m_width = width;
    m_height = height;
    m_textureID = textureID;
    m_currentRow = 1;
    m_currentFrame = 1;
    if(!TextureManager::Instance()->load(name, textureID, pRenderer))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void GameObject::draw(SDL_Renderer* pRenderer)
{
    TextureManager::Instance()->drawFrame(m_textureID, m_x, m_y,m_width, m_height, m_currentRow, m_currentFrame, pRenderer);
}

void GameObject::update()
{
    m_x += 1;
    m_currentFrame = int(((SDL_GetTicks() / 100) % 6));
}

void GameObject::clean()
{

}
```

In my Player class, I do the same thing except I use the methods that are already made in GameObject

Player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include "GameObject.h"
class Player : public GameObject
{
    public:
        bool load(int x, int y, int width, int height, std::string name, std::string textureID, SDL_Renderer* pRenderer);
        void draw(SDL_Renderer* pRenderer);
        void update();
        void clean();
};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"

bool Player::load(int x, int y, int width, int height, std::string name, std::string textureID, SDL_Renderer* pRenderer)
{
    if(!GameObject::load(x, y, width, height, name, textureID, pRenderer))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void Player::draw(SDL_Renderer* pRenderer)
{
    GameObject::draw(pRenderer);
}


void Player::update()
{
    m_currentFrame = int(((SDL_GetTicks() / 100) % 6));
    m_x -= 1;
}


void Player::clean()
{

}
```

This is the part where the images doesn't load the same thing happens in Game.cpp
So I basically created a vector that holds GameObjects, it told me to use it so that I could just for loop through it whenever I want to draw objects

Game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "TextureManager.h"
#include "Player.h"


class Game
{
    public:
        Game() {}
        ~Game() {}

        bool init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, int flags);
        void render();
        void update();
        void handleEvents();
        void clean();


        // a function to access the private running variable
        bool running() { return m_bRunning; }

    private:
        SDL_Window* m_pWindow;
        SDL_Renderer* m_pRenderer;
        int m_currentFrame;
        bool m_bRunning;
        GameObject* m_go;
        GameObject* m_player;
        std::vector<GameObject*> m_gameObjects;


};

#endif
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"


typedef TextureManager TheTextureManager; // Singleton TextureManager
Game* g_game = 0; // Game Object

bool Game::init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width,int height, int flags)
{
    // attempt to initialize SDL



    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL init success\n";
        // init the window
        m_pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xpos, ypos,width, height, flags);
        if(m_pWindow != 0) // window init success
    {
    std::cout << "window creation success\n";
    m_pRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_pWindow, -1, 0);
    if(m_pRenderer != 0) // renderer init success
    {
        std::cout << "renderer creation success\n";
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(m_pRenderer,255,255,255,255);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "renderer init fail\n";
        return false; // renderer init fail
    }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "window init fail\n";
        return false; // window init fail
    }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "SDL init fail\n";
        return false; // SDL init fail
    }
    std::cout << "init success\n";

    m_go = new GameObject();
    m_player = new Player();
    m_go->load(100, 100, 96, 60, "assets/simba.bmp", "animate",m_pRenderer);
    m_player->load(300, 300, 96, 60, "assets/download.bmp", "animate",m_pRenderer);
    m_gameObjects.push_back(m_go);
    m_gameObjects.push_back(m_player);


    m_bRunning = true; // everything inited successfully, start the main loop
    return true;

}

void Game::render()
{
    SDL_RenderClear(m_pRenderer); // clear the renderer to the draw color

    //m_go.draw(m_pRenderer);
    //m_player.draw(m_pRenderer);
    for(std::vector<GameObject*>::size_type i = 0; i != m_gameObjects.size(); i++)
    {
        m_gameObjects[i]->draw(m_pRenderer);
    }

    SDL_RenderPresent(m_pRenderer); // draw to the screen
}

void Game::clean()
{
    std::cout << "cleaning game\n";
    SDL_DestroyWindow(m_pWindow);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(m_pRenderer);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void Game::handleEvents()
{
    SDL_Event event;
    if(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            m_bRunning = false;
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
void Game::update()
{
    //m_currentFrame = int(((SDL_GetTicks() / 100) % 6));
    //m_go.update();
    //m_player.update();
    for(std::vector<GameObject*>::size_type i = 0; i != m_gameObjects.size(); i++)
    {
        m_gameObjects[i]->update();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    g_game = new Game();
    g_game->init("Chapter 1", 100, 100, 640, 480, 0);
    while(g_game->running())
    {
        g_game->render();
        g_game->handleEvents();
        g_game->update();
        SDL_Delay(10); // add the delay
    }
    g_game->clean();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see at the end of the init function, I have m_go load up simba, and m_player load up download. Even though they move in different directions (GameObject moves to the right and Player moves to the left as you can see in the classes in update method).

My program only loads download for both.

I'm not sure if the TextureManager class is related but I'll post it anyway
TextureManager.h

```
#ifndef TEXTUREMANAGER_H
#define TEXTUREMANAGER_H


#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
class TextureManager
{
    public:
        bool load(std::string fileName,std::string id,SDL_Renderer* pRenderer);
        void draw(std::string id, int x, int y, int width, int height, SDL_Renderer* pRenderer, SDL_RendererFlip flip = SDL_FLIP_NONE);
        void drawFrame(std::string id, int x, int y, int width, int height, int currentRow, int currentFrame, SDL_Renderer* pRenderer, SDL_RendererFlip flip = SDL_FLIP_NONE);
        std::map <std::string, SDL_Texture*> m_textureMap;

        static TextureManager* Instance()
        {
            if(s_pInstance == 0)
            {
                s_pInstance = new TextureManager();
                return s_pInstance;
            }
        return s_pInstance;
        }
        //typedef TextureManager TheTextureManager;
    protected:
    private:
        TextureManager(){}
        static TextureManager* s_pInstance;

};

#endif // TEXTUREMANAGER_H
```

TextureManager.cpp

```
#include "TextureManager.h"

TextureManager* TextureManager::s_pInstance = 0;

bool TextureManager::load(std::string fileName, std::string id, SDL_Renderer* pRenderer)
{
    SDL_Surface* pTempSurface = IMG_Load(fileName.c_str());
    if(pTempSurface == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    SDL_Texture* pTexture =
    SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(pRenderer, pTempSurface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(pTempSurface);
    // everything went ok, add the texture to our list
    if(pTexture != 0)
    {
        m_textureMap[id] = pTexture;
        return true;
    }
// reaching here means something went wrong
    return false;
}

void TextureManager::draw(std::string id, int x, int y, int width, int height, SDL_Renderer* pRenderer, SDL_RendererFlip flip)
{
    SDL_Rect srcRect;
    SDL_Rect destRect;

    srcRect.x = 0;
    srcRect.y = 0;
    srcRect.w = destRect.w = width;
    srcRect.h = destRect.h = height;
    destRect.x = x;
    destRect.y = y;
    SDL_RenderCopyEx(pRenderer, m_textureMap[id], &srcRect,
    &destRect, 0, 0, flip);
}

void TextureManager::drawFrame(std::string id, int x, int y, int width, int height, int currentRow, int currentFrame, SDL_Renderer *pRenderer, SDL_RendererFlip flip)
{
    SDL_Rect srcRect;
    SDL_Rect destRect;
    srcRect.x = width * currentFrame;
    srcRect.y = height * (currentRow - 1);
    srcRect.w = destRect.w = width;
    srcRect.h = destRect.h = height;
    destRect.x = x;
    destRect.y = y;
    SDL_RenderCopyEx(pRenderer, m_textureMap[id], &srcRect,
    &destRect, 0, 0, flip);
}
```

Comment: Well, you posted too much code.  Having said that, your GameObject needs to have a virtual destructor, otherwise you will leak memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using "animate" more than once for the `textureID` - this needs to be unique

Your Code:

```
m_go->load(100, 100, 96, 60, "assets/simba.bmp", "animate", m_pRenderer);    
m_player->load(300, 300, 96, 60, "assets/download.bmp", "animate", m_pRenderer)
```

What happens is the texture is loaded but it overwrites the existing texture which has the "animate" key in the map. Make them unique and this should resolve your issue.